# How to make React Context as a global one?

Tags: reactjs

I'm setting up a new project, While doing, I got some doubt on this ? We create context like this :

```
import {createContext} from 'react';

const Context = createContext({});

export default Context;
```

and this context provide,Provider and Consumer right ! Say like I need multiple contexts in the same project, So I will create

```
const MyContext = React.createContext()
const ThemeContext = React.createContext()
```

and this will have

```
 <MyContext.Provider value={greeting}> and <ThemeContext.Provider value={color}>
```

Instead creating `React.createContext()` multiple times like this, Can we do like below?

Creating Context like normally `const Context = createContext({});`
 but we can use it anywhere in the project like :

many `Context.Provider and consumers`. Reason to doing this is, We should create createContext every time like above, How about create it globally and  make an instance to use Providers and Consumers multiple times with Single CreateContext , Is this possible ?

Consider a project setup like this ?

```
rootFolder
   actions
   reducers
   containers
   components
   contextAPI
   fetchCalls
```

all are folders. contextAPI contains createContext() globally. I'd like to implement many Providers by creating an instance of it , like an obj, create it and make an instance of it to use it elsewhere instead creating an obj everytime ? Is it a right  pattern ?

sample stuff I need to achieve is,

```
function Course (name, grade) {
  this.name = name;
  this.grade = grade;
}

var course = new Course ('react', 10); // prints {name: "react", grade: 10}
var course = new Course ('data', 10); //prints {name: "data", grade: 10}
```

Comment: About wrapping all `Provider`s into one, I think you could just create a component let's call `Contexts` and wrap it all, leverage the  `props.children` and it'll work, you'll only need to wrap context consumer inside `<Contexts.Provider>..consumer components..</Contexts.Provider>` instead of <MyContext.Provider><ThemeContext.Provider>.. consumer components.. </ThemeContext.Provider></MyContext.Provider>. About `consume` the context, is it `useContext` hook is already easy enough?

Comment: I guess, I am not getting it, sorry let me clearly expose your comment again ?

Comment: How do you usually consume your Context? `<YourContext.Consumer>` or `useContext` ?

Comment: Ah, maybe I misunderstood your question, let's wait for someone else..

Comment: When the app grows context also grows right so every time we have to write createContext to get Provider, Consumer, but what I'm thinking is write single createContext and get Provider, Consumer every time you need like object instance